# What are some examples of infinite state quantum mechanical systems that do not involve free particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

That is, the quanta are in bound states where there are least upper bounds and greatest lower bounds to their energy states but there are at least a countably infinite many energy levels they can assume? I'm particularly interested in examples of entangled systems with this property. Any physical examples that can be created in the laboratory?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're asking. What do you mean by least upper bounds? Are looking for a system whose energy is bounded above and below? If so, the hydrogen atom is an example.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, an electron (or a hole) in a doped semiconductor meets your requirements;  there are an (effectively) infinite number of energy levels available to these particles between the Fermi sea and the binding energy (work function) of the semi-conductor.

Comment: Dave, does Spice Ice also meet these requirements? Like the qasiparticles in Dysprosium Titanate for example..

Comment: @MrX Don't know for sure.  might be worth asking as its own question.